# string convert in array Ios , get by webservices

Tags: ios, nsarray

In ios i am using Xml soap parsing This is my response

```
<InsertResponse xmlns="http://OrderMe.solyn.in/"><InsertResult>[{"Result":"Success","AccessToken":"f60da1f1-40d7-483d-880a-82348dc20934","AppUserId":"35"}]</InsertResult></InsertResponse>
```

Then i am using This code for Get Response

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (elementFound) {
       // NSLog(@"%@",soapResults);
        [soapResults appendString: string];
        if ([Type isEqualToString:@"InsertResponse"] ) {
            //--- Retrieving text of an element that is found---
            NSLog(@"%@",string);
            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:string encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSArray *allData = [str JSONValue];

            //NSString *loginID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
            //NSLog(@"Login ID Returned from web service is : %@",loginID);
        }
    }
}
```

in this code ** NSLog(@"%@",string);** this string is print

```
[{"Result":"Success","AccessToken":"f60da1f1-40d7-483d-880a-82348dc20934","AppUserId":"35"}]
```

so i dont know how to convert this string in array 
I am wating response 
please share your valuable knowledge 
Regards, 
Nishant Chandwani 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse this string as JSON:

```
NSString *string = @"[{\"Result\":\"Success\",\"AccessToken\":\"f60da1f1-40d7-483d-880a-82348dc20934\",\"AppUserId\":\"35\"}]";
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

First this is xml parser.So how can we get the values from this.Let's come to below coding

In your .h part

//Step 1 : Add the Delegate classes

```
     First of all you should add <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

//Step 2 : Create necessary objects

```
     NSXMLParser *parser;
     NSMutableData *ReceviedData;
     NSMutableString *currentStringValue;

     NSMutableArray *arrayResult;
     NSMutableArray *arrayAccessToken;
     NSMutableArray *arrayAppUserId;
```

In your .m part

```
 //Step 3 - Allocate your all  Arrays in your viewDidLoad method

     arrayAppUserId = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     arrayResult = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     arrayAccessToken = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 //Step 4 - Create Connection in your viewDidLoad Like 

     [self createConnection:@"http://www.google.com"];//give your valid url.

-(void)createConnection:(NSString *)urlString
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  //Step 5 - parser delegate methods are using NSURLConnectionDelegate class or not.
    BOOL success;
    if (!parser)
    {
      parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
      parser.delegate = self;
      parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = YES;
      success = [parser parse];
      NSLog(@"Success : %c",success);
    }
  }

   -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
  {
      NSLog(@"Current Element Name : %@",elementName);

     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"])
     {
         NSLog(@"The Result is==%@",elementName);
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AccessToken"])
     {
         NSLog(@"The AccessToken is==%@",elementName);
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AppUserId"])
     {
         NSLog(@"The appUserId is==%@",elementName);
     }
  }

  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
  {
    currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
     NSLog(@"Current String Value : %@",currentStringValue);
  }

  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   {
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"])
     {
       [arrayResult addObject:currentStringValue];
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AccessToken"])
     {
       [arrayAccessToken addObject:currentStringValue];
     }
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AppUserId"])
     {
       [arrayAppUserId addObject:currentStringValue];
     }
      currentStringValue = nil;
  }
```